# Cómo puedo coger los datos de otra tabla según el código

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

Me gustaría saber como puedo recoger los datos de otra tabla. Quiero que de la tabla fichador cuando el usuario introduzca su código se rellene el nombre cogiéndolo de la tabla empleado, ¿qué debería hacer?

```
Models:
OPCIONES_TIPO = (
    ('Entrada', 'Entrada'),
    ('Salida', 'Salida')
)

class fichador(models.Model):
    Codigo =  models.CharField('codigo', max_length=10)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    nombre_persona = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=50)
    tipo = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_TIPO,
                            max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    tipo_auten = models.CharField('tipo_autentificacion', max_length=50, default='Tarjeta')

class empleado(models.Model):
    Codigo = models.ForeignKey(fichador, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    nombre_persona = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=7)

Views
class fichador_view(CreateView):
    model = fichador
    fields = ['Codigo', 'tipo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['fichador'] = fichador.objects.all()
        return context
```

[image: Imagen BD Empleado]
[image: Imagen Fichador]

Comment: La pregunta principal sería, ¿cada usuario ficha por sí mismo? ¿puede otra persona fichar por ellos? Si el usuario tiene que estar autentificado en el sistema (login), entonces puedes recoger el dato en la vista (aunque en tu modelo no parece que estén relacionados user y persona).

Comment: Si cada usuario pone el codigo suyo propio que tiene y ya esta

Comment: No me respondes a lo básico, ¿el usuario tiene que estar autentificado (logeado) en el sistema? Si es así ya tienes todos los datos posibles, solo te falta relacionar Persona con User

Comment: No hace falta el login

Comment: Más allá del problema de seguridad que supone (cualquiera puede fichar por un empleado), lo que tienes que hacer sería un formulario que recoja el código y pasarlo como argumento a la url de fichar. De hecho el mismo formulario puede recoger si es entrada/salida y el código de empleado.

Comment: Pero ahi como saco el nombre del empleado?¿ A mi me interesa que cuando introduzcan el codigo busque a la tabla de empleados y saque el nombre

Comment: En el contexto de la vista. Sin más detalles de los formularios, vistas, urls y flujo deseado no puedo responder.

Comment: Por que necesitas traer de vuelta el nombre del la tabla Empleado si en Fichador ya tienes un campo de nombre_persona? no te es mas sencillo sacarlo de ese campo que ya está en Fichador?

Comment: El formulario solo es ese que se crea solo, necesito que ese campo nombre_persona se rellene buscando al empleado por código, porque en el formulario no se rellena campo persona solo se rellena el código.